# Get RAW-Response from RestTemplate

Tags: java, spring, resttemplate

I'm trying to retrieve the raw-reponse from a Spring RestTemplate

```
String get = restTemplate.postForObject(url, params, String.class);
```

But since the server responds with `Content-Type: Application/Json` Spring tries to map the Response to a String-Object by parsing it. Which leads in my case to

```
Cannot deserialize instance of `java.lang.String` out of START_ARRAY token
```

since the response contains a json array. Is it possible to get the raw response without parsing? Or do i have to use something other than the RestTemplate?

You can try the problem with these examples

```
restTemplate.getForEntity("https://api.github.com/users/hadley/orgs", String.class);
restTemplate.getForObject("https://api.github.com/users/hadley/orgs", String.class);
```

Comment: https://www.baeldung.com/rest-template - use postforEntity

Comment: @MarcStröbel this produces the same error

Comment: any custom deserializers registered for this resttemplate instance? Same error if using a plain new RestTemplate?

Comment: Maybe also add what Spring/Spring boot version you are using.

Comment: @MarcStroebel you where right, there seems to be a forced message converter MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter configured in my spring application

Comment: Strange that i tried the same and it worked for me, do you have any specific customization on rest template, also response header as returned from this api is `application/json; charset=utf-8` as seen in postman

Answer (score 0):

Please try following the code

```java
 @GetMapping(path = "raw")
    public String raw() {
        String response = restTemplate.getForObject("http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users", String.class);
        System.out.println("Length: " + response.length());
        return response;
    }
```

My RestTemplate looks like this

```java
@Configuration
    public static class Beaner {
        @Bean
        public RestTemplate restTemplate() {
            return new RestTemplate();
        }
    }
```